# Conditional Probability- With replacement

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Say a bag contains 2 white balls and 3 black balls. 3 balls are drawn randomly with replacement.
a. Find the P(1st is white | 2nd is black)
b. Find the P(1st is white | at least 1 black ball is drawn)

For a. I found the P(W)=2/5 and the P(B)=3/5, then I multiplied those together to get 6/25. Then I used the formula for condition probability P(WB)/P(2nd is B)= (6/25)/(3/5)= 2/5, is this correct?

And then for b. I got stuck at P(at least 1 ball is B), I know I should do 1-P(only white balls are drawn) and to find that I thought about doing 5C2/5C3. Is this the correct way to find the P(at least 1 black ball is drawn?

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote $B_1, B_2, B_3$ to represent the *independent* events of drawing a black ball in the indicated draw; and likewise their corresponding complements shall be $W_1, W_2, W_3$.

(a) No need to multiply then divide by the same thing.   It is simply that $\mathsf P(W_1\mid B_2)= \mathsf P(W_1)$ since these events are independent (vis "with replacement"), so the result *is as you had*: $\mathsf P(W_1\mid B_2)= 2/5$

$$\mathsf P(W_1\mid B_2)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(W_1)\,\require{cancel}\cancel{\mathsf P(B_2)}}{\cancel{\mathsf P(B_2)}}$$

(b) "At least one is black" is the event $B_1\cup B_2\cup B_3$, and this will be the complement of $W_1\cap W_2\cap W_3$, *as you reasoned*.  **However**, there will be no binomial coefficients involved in this evaluation, as the draws are made *with replacement*.

The definition of conditional probability, and the independence of the draws, leads to:

$$\mathsf P(W_1\mid B_1\cup B_2\cup B_3)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(W_1\cap( B_2\cup B_3) )}{\mathsf P(B_1\cup B_2\cup B_3)}=\dfrac{\mathsf P(W_1)\,(1-\mathsf P(W_2)\,\mathsf P(W_3))}{1-\mathsf P(W_1)\,\mathsf P(W_2)\,\mathsf P(W_3)}$$

Comment: So for b, since it is also independent I don't even really need to divide because it will be equal to the P(W), correct?

Comment: No, @EmmaBanashak , you do need to divide because $W_1$ is *not* independent from $B_1\cup B_2\cup B_3$. $$B_1\cup B_2\cup B_3= [W_1\cap(B_2\cup B_3)]\cup[B_1]$$

Answer (score 0):

Your answer for (a) is correct.

For (b) the probability is as you suggest  $1-(\frac{2}{5})^3=\frac{117}{125}$.

On the top line you have the probability that the first ball is white and then the next two balls are not both white. This is $(\frac{2}{5})(1-(\frac{2}{5})^2)=\frac{42}{125}$.

So the conditional probability is $\frac{42}{117}.$

Answer (score 0):

(a) You're right. Notice that the multiplication you did is justified because the events B and W are independent (because the balls are drawn with replacement), and the $P(B)$ cancels out in the end. In general, such a calculation shows that if A and B are independent events then $P(A|B)=P(A)$, which matches our intuition about what "independence" is.

(b) You're right that you want to find $1-P(A)$ where $A$ is the event that only white balls are drawn. Remember that we're drawing with replacement, so each draw is independent. Therefore, $P(A)=P(\text{all balls white})=P(\text{first ball white})P(\text{second ball white})P(\text{third ball white})=\frac23\frac23\frac23.$